# How to fix the ApiValidator issue (ApiValidation: Error: XXX.sys has unsupported API call to "ntoskrnl.exe!KeGetCurrentIrql")

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10, driver, windows-10-universal, windows-driver

I am developing the system driver for Windows 10 and trying to pass the ApiValidator.

I can pass the ApiValidator in VS2019 environment. But I can't pass it in HLK environment.

I am getting `ApiValidation: Error: XXX.sys has unsupported API call to "ntoskrnl.exe!KeGetCurrentIrql"` issue in HLK environment.

**Environments:**

- VS 2019: WDK 10.0.20348.0
- HLK:

  - Controller Version: 10.1.19041.19041
  - Studio Version: 10.0.19041.1

I think the problem is because the `UniversalDDIs.xml` file of HLK is older than the `UniversalDDIs.xml` file of VS2019.

I shared the UniversalDDIs.xml files.

- [VS2019_UniversalDDIs.xml](https://gist.github.com/li-apporto/a81bc4c6f08dcd5a2e2e9209e552be4a) (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\build\universalDDIs\x64\UniversalDDIs.xml)
- [HLK_UniversalDDIs.xml](https://gist.github.com/li-apporto/9481db6ebb8043e51751d6cb1fa18c06) (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Hardware Lab Kit\Tests\amd64\ApiValidator\amd64_UniversalDDIs.xml)

Could you help me with?

Thank you

Li

Answer (score 0):

Specify in your `.vcxproj` file, in `PropertyGroup Label="Globals"` entry:

```
<ApiValidator_Enable>false</ApiValidator_Enable>
```